# getting an error while fetching data from json api in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api

E/flutter ( 7802):
E/flutter ( 7802): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 7802): widget_price_filter .price_label, .shop-filters .woocommerce-result-count,....
E/flutter ( 7802): ^
E/flutter ( 7802):

Comment: you need to share more details

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question